# How to combine two RGB images without having white space between them

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to combine some parts of the image together while still maintaining some parts unchanged.

This is first image

[image: mask]

This is the code to get the first image, the parameter for the input are img which is original image but already colorized with green while jawline,eyebrows,etc are (x,y) coordinates to cut those parts from the image

```
def getmask(img,jawline,eyebrows,eyes,mouth):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    imArray = np.asarray(img)
    # create mask
    polygon = jawline.flatten().tolist()
    maskIm = Image.new('L', (imArray.shape[1], imArray.shape[0]), 0)
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill='white')
    #ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=(1))
    # draw eyes
    righteyes=eyes[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(righteyes, outline=1, fill='black')
    lefteyes=eyes[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(lefteyes, outline=1, fill='black')
    # draw eyebrows
    rightbrows=eyebrows[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(rightbrows, outline=2, fill='black')
    leftbrows=eyebrows[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(leftbrows, outline=2, fill='black')
    # draw mouth
    mouth=mouth.flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(mouth, outline=1, fill='black')

    mask = np.array(maskIm)
    mask = np.multiply(img,mask)+ np.multiply((1-mask),np.ones((L,P,3)))
    return mask
```

This is the second image which will fill the white blank inside the first image

[image: cut]

I used this code to cut the parts which is very similar to the code on first image.

```
def getface(img,eyebrows,eyes,mouth):
    im=img.copy()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    imArray = np.asarray(img)
    # create mask
    maskIm = Image.new('L', (imArray.shape[1], imArray.shape[0]), 0)
    righteyes=eyes[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(righteyes, outline=1,fill='white')
    lefteyes=eyes[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(lefteyes, outline=1,fill='white')
    # draw eyebrows
    rightbrows=eyebrows[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(rightbrows, outline=2, fill='white')
    leftbrows=eyebrows[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(leftbrows, outline=2, fill='white')
    # draw mouth
    mouth=mouth.flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(mouth, outline=1, fill='white')
    cutted_part = np.array(maskIm)
    cutted_part = cv2.bitwise_or(im,im,mask=mask)
    return cutted_part
```

So far I have tried to combine those two images by first inversing the second image so that the black background become white and then multiply the first and second image. But the result isn't satisfactory.

[image: result]

As you can see, there are some white space between the combined area and I notice that some part from second image become smaller or missing which I suspect create those white space when combined (Please don't mind the slightly different color on the result). Maybe someone can share how to resolve this problem or has better ways to combine 2 images together?

Answer (score -1):

If you provide your results as actual pictures instead of cropped screenshots we can reproduce your problem, so far i would recommend:

Invert the background of your cutout (black to white) and then simply combine both pictures either by adding them (They need to have the same dimensions, which i presume is the case.) or overlaying them by using opencv's `addWeighted` function to adjust opacity.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your input. I have added more details on my post. I hope it can give you more details to help me